# Why items are not showing

Tags: sapui5

I create a grid table, that rows bounded to a model:

```
<table:Table id="terminal-table"
             inset="false"
             rows="{vmTerminals>/aCurrent}"
             class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
  <table:title>
    <Label text="Terminal"/>
  </table:title>
  <table:columns>
    <table:Column>
      <Label text="Computer"/>
      <table:template>
        <Text text="{Computer}"/>
      </table:template>
    </table:Column>
    <table:Column>
      <Label text="Plant"/>
      <table:template>
        <Text text="{Plant}"/>
      </table:template>
    </table:Column>
    <table:Column>
      <Label text="Work center"/>
      <table:template>
        <Text text="{WorkCenter}"/>
      </table:template>
    </table:Column>
  </table:columns>
</table:Table>
```

The items of the model looks as follow:
[image]

The table shows no items:
[image]
But as you can see, the table recognize three items on the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do: Add the model name for the relative bindings inside the aggregation.

```
 <Text text="{Computer}"/>
```

needs to be

```
<Text text="{vmTerminals>Computer}"/>
```